# How to make work a String ng-model for angular ng-options using an Object Literal Array of alternatives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Given an `ng-model` as `$scope.value = "b"`, how would I declare the syntax for `ng-options` to be able to select and save the `value` property of the following alternatives?

```
$scope.value = "b"
$scope.alternatives = [{
  text: "A",
  value: "a"
}, {
  text: "B",
  value: "b"
}, {
  text: "C",
  value: "c"
}];
```

What I want is that, when an option is selected, the model changes to lowercase "b". Currently it saves to the whole Object `{"text":"B","value":"b"}`

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/oupwDU8BZQ2WsJDeYbTv?p=preview

Comment: It would be very useful a justification for the "-1" on this question. Just because there is a duplicate answer, it doesn't mean this is a bad question, it just means I failed to find the duplicate due to the fact the duplicate doesn't express this specific context in the title, but rather a generic approach on how to handle `ng-options`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do:

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="obj.value as obj.text for obj in alternatives"></select>
```